# How to print part of a line PART 2

Tags: regex, file, groovy, line, capture

Using Groovy, I wish to grab two parts of a tab-separated line.  Take the example line:

`one    fish    two    fish    red   fish    blue    fish` ----(each character tab `/t` separated)

Suppose I want to print `one`  and then I want to print `red fish    blue`

How can I do this?

Alternatively, suppose I want to print `one` and then a count of the number of characters (words) following `red`?  Or between `two and blue`?

A previous question yielded this response for printing everything following a certain part of the line:

```
c = ~/.*red(.*)/

m = line =~ c
if (m) {
println m[0][1]
}
```

to yield `fish blue fish` but I'm not comptetent enough with regex's to modify this appropriately.  I've tried a few iterations, inserting `/t` in there and modifying my capturing expression but I've not figured it out.  This is three or four questions in one, any help is appreciated.  Thanks!!

Comment: Split on tabs, in the resulting array get the first element and count the elements you want.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm a total newb.  How do I split on tabs?

Comment: Thanks Qtax, I found an example to use : `http://jonstefansson.blogspot.com/2008/05/groovy-database-script.html`

Comment: You should probably answer this question your self and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def a = [:].withDefault{[]}
def b = [:].withDefault{[]}
def c = 0
def d = 0
def e = 0
def f = 0

seuss = "one\tfish\ttwo\tfish\tred\tfish\tblue\tfish"
a = seuss.split (/\t/)

for (i =0; i<a.size(); i++) {
 if (d != 0) {
    c = c + 1
}
if ( a[i] == "red") {
    d = i
}

}

println a[4] + '\t' + c

for (i =0; i<a.size(); i++) {
if ( a[i] == "blue") {
    e = 0
}
 if (e != 0) {
    f = f + 1
}
if ( a[i] == "two") {
    e = i
}


}

println a[0] + '\t' + f
```